Account report filtered by role hierarchy
My main goal is to create an account report that shows accounts owned by anyone in one team (Business Development). I need to include the manager and reps in the report. The reps themselves are always changing, so I don't want to use their names to filter. Using "My and my teams Accounts" would work, except that doesn't help any of that persons supervisors look at the report. I tried running the report with the role field, but no luck, I'm open to suggestions.
What I specifically tried was creating a filter for owner role. I tried using greater than and less than, hoping that would show records owned by people above and below in the hierarchy, but it doesn't quite work. For some reason one or two roles that should be "less than" are showing up when filtering by "greater than". It's not hierarchy, or alphabetical, I'm not sure what the rule there is.
This works great on opportunity reports, as the role filter is built into the "Show Me" filter. But that isn't possible on account reports.
